# Removing an application from homebrew-cask

Tags: install, software-update, homebrew

Homebrew-cask provides the possibility for users to conveniently install the applications with GUI, I want to confirm that: while I try to uninstall a software which was installed by homebrew-cask, will it remove those `Application Supports`, `Caches`, or related files too?

By the way, If I manually update a software (which was installed by cask) without using command provided by cask, will it corrupt the cask function (such as updating that software in the future with cask again)?

Answer (score 7):

To remove an application cask via Homebrew-cask, run this command: `brew uninstall --force --cask <cask_name>`

Comment: The `force` command was necessary for me. Currently running OS X Catalina. Thank you!

Comment: 2021 Nov, this command worked, top answer had old syntax

Answer (score 6):

For full remove try:

```
brew cask zap any_program
```

Manual update should not corrupt anything. It updates the same program copy which was installed by cask.

Comment: in 2021 Nov: this gives me error unknown command cask, other answer with modified syntax worked.

Answer (score 4):

No, uninstalling from brew-cask’s `uninstall` command will not remove the files in Application Support, Caches, Preferences etc. For that you’ll need  a third party app, like AppCleaner or iTrash. I just delete one app this way and it didn’t even remove the symlink it made to the `~/Applications/` folder.

Though homebrew cask is an easy solution for installing app, it’ not perfect. On the man page of `brew-cask` you can read about the problems with uninstall command.  You can use the `zap` command that does a little more than uninstall but that too has limitations, see the man page.

I don’t know if updating app will corrupt, have never tried it. You might have to `fetch` information for the cask using the command, or even re-install it with `fetch —-force`.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [@user14492](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/183125/96174) answer, which is right, check out the last line of the following paragraph, that answer your last question.

> **Updating/Upgrading Casks**
>
> Since the homebrew-cask repository is a Homebrew Tap, you'll pull down
>   the latest Casks every time you issue the regular Homebrew command
>   `brew update`. Currently, homebrew-cask cannot always detect if an
>   Application has been updated. You can force an update via the command
>   `brew cask install --force`. We are working on improving this.
>
> ***It is generally safe to run updates from within an Application***.

Source: [How to Use Homebrew-cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md).